# Image plane, camera location and real distance

Tags: geometric-optics, geometry

Suppose I have a situation as shown in the image bellow. A 3D-Object I want to project into a 2D-Image with respect to the real distance. But I don't really understand the connection between the distance to the "camera location" (on the right) and the distance to the image plane.

How do I have to choose the distance between the camera location and the image plane to get a result I would expect in reality?

[image]

Comment: could you please clarify: you know or example the vertices of your object in reality , you want to draw it on a computer screen ? you know the size it should have an the screen, or the distance you assume from object to screen?

Comment: There will be two similar triangles for each pair of rays of light. The magnification and relevant distances can be calculated from there.

Comment: What do you mean by "in reality"? What is the real situation you want to achieve?

Comment: I have a "real" distance between the object on the left and the "human eye" on the right. With "in reality" I mean that I want the 2D-Image that a person at that point would see. Therefore I have to choose the right distance between the 2D-Plane and the observer. But I don't know how that fits together.